# Rails - Rubber - the setup_remote_aliases task gets "stuck" with the message "sftp upload #StringIO:0x103bf1068 ->

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy my app to AWS using rubber.

But the setup_remote_aliases task gets "stuck" with the message "sftp upload #StringIO:0x103bf1068 ->

On trying cap rubber:refresh, it again gets stuck at the same point. I have a micro instance set up - Can it be because of that?

Here are the logs:

```
 Instance running, fetching hostname/ip data
  * executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["23.20.223.139"]
 ** Can't connect as user ubuntu to 23.20.223.139, assuming root allowed
  * executing `rubber:_direct_connection_23.20.223.139_794'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["23.20.223.139"]
    [23.20.223.139] executing command
 ** [out :: 23.20.223.139] Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.
 ** [out :: 23.20.223.139] 
    command finished in 11086ms
  * executing `rubber:setup_static_ips'
  * executing `rubber:setup_local_aliases'
 ** Writing out aliases into local machines /etc/hosts, sudo access needed
Password:
 ** Auto role: apache => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: app => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: passenger => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: collectd => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: common => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: monit => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: db => production.foo.com, {:primary=>true, :platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql_master => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: elasticsearch => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: examples => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graphite_server => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graphite_web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_elasticsearch => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_mongodb => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: mongodb => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_server => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: haproxy => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: web_tools => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
  * executing `rubber:setup_remote_aliases'
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x0000010477db48> -> /tmp/setup_remote_aliases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know what the exact problem is, I had this kind of problem using rubber too. I found adding more debug info to rubber is very useful.

For your case, you can find where the task is defined and simply log some message.

```
grep -r setup_remote_aliases `bundle show rubber`
```

Also you might want to try Amazon Elastic Beanstalk which supports rails app deployment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1680

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server instance is ok.other's may be some problem. try it.